# flask- displaying a list from SQL Server

Tags: flask

I am trying to get a customer list from SQL Server and display it in web page as drop down list. The page works fine (displays the title) but there is nothing displayed for customer list and there are no errors.

I tested the SQL result by printing it after fetch and it works fine. Also displayed the result in the webpage as a paragraph and again all the customer name is displayed in a paragraph. The only thing missing is how to have the customer name and id in a drop down list (or just customer name in a drop down).

This is my code and related html:

```
@app.route('/about')
def about():
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL 
            server};server=xxx;database="";uid="";pwd="";")

     result_df=pd.read_sql("select distinct Customer_Name,Customer_Id from 
                            table_x where period='Q3 2018'",cnxn)
    cnxn.close()
    print (result_df) # The print here worked fine , I could see all cust
    return render_template('customer.html',result_df=result_df)
```

Customer.html:

```
{% block body %}

<h1>Sample ECL customer list</h1>
<p>{{result_df}}</p>   -- this line works fine display all the customer id and name as a paragraph.

<div class="large-8 columns">
    <div class="row container1">
               {% for result_df in result_df %}

                <div class="large-4 small-4 columns">
                       <ul>
                           {% if result_df.Customer_Name %}<li>{{ result_df.Customer_Name }}</li>{% endif %}
                      <!--     {% if result_df.Customer_Id %}<li 
class="price">${{ result_df.customer_id }}</li>{% endif %} -->
                       </ul>
                </div>
               {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Could you show the results of result_df variable?

Comment: Customer Name Customer Id
ABC 123
DEF 345

Answer (score 0):

Therefore that the read_sql method returns dataframes. You can easily get data in view via keys(Customer_Name,Customer_Id)

```
{% for result in result_df %}
    <div class="large-4 small-4 columns">
           <ul>
                {% if result["Customer_Name"] %}<li>{{ result["Customer_Name"] }}</li>{% endif %}
                {% if result["Customer_Id"] %}
                <li class="price">${{ result["Customer_Id"] }}</li>
                {% endif %} 
           </ul>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried the below code, still no result and no errors
<div class="large-8 columns">
        <div class="row container1">
                   {% for result in result_df %}
                    <div>
                           <ul>
                               {% if result["Customer_Name"]  %}<li>{{ result["Customer_Name"] }}</li>{% endif %}
                                {% if result["Customer_Id"] %}<li>{{ result["Customer_Id"] }}</li>{% endif %}
                           </ul>
                    </div>
                   {% endfor %}
        </div>
 </div>
{% endblock %}